# Is there an PowerQuery function or formula to remove (duplicate) rows when particular conditions are met

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to transform a financial dataset into a more appropriate form. As the dataset has a lot of rows that are almost identical and need to be removed if the sum of column "value" is equal to zero.

| Category | Number | Supplier | Value | Cost center | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Application to order | 1001 | 150 | + 121 | 100 | Text A |
| Application to order | 1001 | 150 | - 121 | 100 | Text A |
| Application to order | 1002 | 142 | + 115 | 120 | Text B |
| Application to order | 1002 | 142 | - 89 | 120 | Text B |
| Order | 1003 | 88 | + 276 | 160 | Text C |
| Order | 1003 | 88 | - 272 | 160 | Text C |
| Order | 1004 | 14 | + 890 | 180 | Text D |
| Order | 1004 | 14 | - 890 | 180 | Text D |

I would like to remove the numbers 1001 and 1004 as the sum of the value is equal to zero.

As I am just starting with PowerQuery my skills are underdeveloped. First thing I tried was to remove duplicate rows, however as the rows are not identical it did not worked out very well. Use Group By on column Category, Supplier and Cost Center. Was almost what I wanted, except only the selected columns where visible and not all columns of the dataset.

The desired output needs to be as follows:

| Category | Number | Supplier | Value | Cost center | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Application to order | 1002 | 142 | + 115 | 120 | Text B |
| Application to order | 1002 | 142 | - 89 | 120 | Text B |
| Order | 1003 | 88 | + 276 | 160 | Text C |
| Order | 1003 | 88 | - 272 | 160 | Text C |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

Group. Filter. Then expand

Group:
[image]

Filter using drop down atop column Sum to uncheck zero:

[image]

Expand using arrow atop the table column:

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Supplier", Int64.Type}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Cost center", Int64.Type}, {"Description", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Category", "Supplier", "Cost center"}, {{"data", each _, type table}, {"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([Sum] <> 0)),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "data", {"Number", "Value", "Description"}, {"Number", "Value", "Description"})
in   #"Expanded data"
```

[image]